# What naming convention for a method/function that both sets and gets a value?

Tags: c, function, naming-conventions

This may come across as a strange question, since the convention is usually to have separate set and get methods.  But in my case, it is a bit different: an argument to a function decides whether that function is a getter or a setter, so I am looking for a function name that will indicate such function.

Some names I have found were getset, setget, rw, and etc but i find these names rather strange.  What kind of naming convention would fit for such functions?

Comment: "an argument to a function decides whether that function is a getter or a setter": make it simple: create two functions: one sets, one gets....

Comment: How about "accessor" ... Also, is there a reason why you can't put getting and setting in 2 different functions?

Comment: I would call it "value"

Comment: ... or "property_xyz" or "prop_xyz" or "prp_xyz" or ....

Answer (score 5):

Until Java beans came along with the get/set naming convention, one quite often saw functions (particularly methods in C++ and other OO languages) that did exactly as you describe.

They were often named after the variable that they set or got, e.g.:

```
int counter_;

int counter () {
    return counter_;
}

int counter (int c) {
    counter_ = c;
    return counter_;
}
```

In languages with different namespaces for variables and functions, you could even have the variable and the get/set functions have exactly the same name (without the need for a trailing _ as I've shown here).

In languages with default parameters, you could potentially write the getter and setter as one function, e.g. something like this:

```
int counter (int c = MAX_INT) {
    if (c != MAX_INT) {
        counter_ = c;
    }
    return counter_;
}
```

... though I wasn't particularly keen on that approach because it led to subtle bugs if someone called `counter (MAX_INT)`, for instance.

I always thought that this naming approach made some sense and I've written some libraries that worked that way.

This naming convention did, however, potentially confuse the reader of the code, particularly in languages where one could call a parameterless function without the trailing parentheses, so it was hard to see if a function was being called or if a public variable was being accessed directly. Of course some would call the latter a feature rather than a problem ...

Answer (score 1):

How about just name the function after the name of the variable it populates? Like a property, when the parameter passed is null or other special value, then it is get, otherwise it is set.